# Pyspark connection to the Microsoft SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, pyspark, odbc, pyodbc

I have a huge dataset in SQL server, I want to Connect the SQL server with python, then use pyspark to run the query.

I've seen the JDBC driver but I don't find the way to do it, I did it with PYODBC but not with a spark.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following to connect to Microsoft SQL:

```
def connect_to_sql(
    spark, jdbc_hostname, jdbc_port, database, data_table, username, password
):
    jdbc_url = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1}/{2}".format(jdbc_hostname, jdbc_port, database)

    connection_details = {
        "user": username,
        "password": password,
        "driver": "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
    }

    df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table=data_table, properties=connection_details)
    return df
```

`spark` is a `SparkSession` object, and the rest are pretty clear.

You can also pass pushdown queries to `read.jdbc`

Comment: thank you for answering, i think i'm close to solve it, but i'm getting problems with the spark session.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i'm getting error with my sparksession, what i have is this:spark = SparkSession.builder\
.config('spark.jars', r'D:\Usuarios\aospinam\Downloads\Microsoft JDBC Driver 7.4 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_7.4\enu\mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8')\
.appName("app2")\
.master("local").getOrCreate()

Comment: @AndresOspina you won't need to add the jars. You can get rid of that config

Comment: how i know if i have a SparkSession well stablished?

Comment: @AndresOspina `SparkSession` `getOrCreate` is not a lazy evaulation function. So when you create it, you should get the error immediately. Let me know what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

I use pissall's function (connect_to_sql) but I modified it a little.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def connect_to_sql(
    spark, jdbc_hostname, jdbc_port, database, data_table, username, password
):
    jdbc_url = "jdbc:mysql://{0}:{1}/{2}".format(jdbc_hostname, jdbc_port, database)

    connection_details = {
        "user": username,
        "password": password,
        "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    }

    df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table=data_table, properties=connection_details)
    return df

if __name__=='__main__':
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName('test') \
        .master('local[*]') \
        .enableHiveSupport() \
        .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", <path to mysql-connector-java-5.1.49-bin.jar>) \
        .getOrCreate()

    df = connect_to_sql(spark, 'localhost', <port>, <database_name>, <table_name>, <user>, <password>)
```

or you can use SparkSession .read method

```
df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url","jdbc:mysql://localhost/<database_name>").option("driver","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable",<table_name>).option("user",<user>).option("password",<password>).load()
```