# How to connect to SQL Server using Pyspark which is running on GCP without using Secure Sockets Layer?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, mssql-jdbc, spark-jdbc

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database using PySpark as below:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import traceback

def connect_and_read(spark: SparkSession):
    url = 'jdbc:sqlserver://DUMMY1234.DUMMY.COM\DUMMY1234;databaseName=Dummy_DB;encrypt=false'
    driver = 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'
    try:
        dataframe = spark.read.format('jdbc').option('url', url). \
            option('driver', driver). \
            option('user', 'username'). \
            option('password', 'password'). \
            option('dbtable', 'TABLENAME'). \
            load()
        print(f'Count: {dataframe.count()}')
        dataframe.take(10)
    except Exception as ex:
        traceback.print_exc(type(ex), ex, ex.__traceback__)
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master('yarn').config('spark.app.name', 'read_data_sqlserver').config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', 'path_to_/mssql-jdbc-9.2.0.jre8.jar').config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', 'path_to_/spark-mssql-connector-1.0.1.jar').getOrCreate()
    connect_and_read(spark)
```

I am running this code from Google Cloud Platform. I have a Dataproc instance where I created a cluster for this operation and submitting my job there. The job fails with below exception:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o70.load.
> : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Connection reset ClientConnectionId:1223412f-9879702-wfwd-134qq-2143d123e1q".
>
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3208)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1916)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2760)
> at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2418)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2265)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1291)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:881)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset ClientConnectionId:1223412f-9879702-wfwd-134qq-2143d123e1q.
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:862)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:849)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:1019)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:1009)
> at org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.readFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:920)
> at org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:884)
> at org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.access$100(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:706)
> at org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:230)
> at org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:209)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1824)
> ... 28 more
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/tmp/portw/pattern.py", line 24, in 
> connect_and_read(spark)
>
> File "/tmp/portw/pattern.py", line 18, in connect_and_read
> traceback.print_exc(type(ex), ex, ex.**traceback**)
>
> File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.8/traceback.py", line 163, in print_exc
> print_exception(*sys.exc_info(), limit=limit, file=file, chain=chain)
>
> File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.8/traceback.py", line 103, in print_exception
> for line in TracebackException(
>
> File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.8/traceback.py", line 509, in **init**
> self.stack = StackSummary.extract(
>
> File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.8/traceback.py", line 340, in extract
> if limit >= 0:
>
> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'int'
>
> 21/02/09 13:59:59 INFO org.sparkproject.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Stopped Spark@1aa73a6d{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}

Earlier, the URL didn't contain `encrypt=false` and I added it after looking at some references.

I am able to connect to the same host for my APIs in plain python code but not in Spark.

Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I am making here and how to correct it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58848735/11866104

Comment: @Mahboob It didn't solve. I checked that question before coming here.

Comment: This exception is probably caused by incompatibility w/ MS SQL JDBC driver and [Conscrypt](https://github.com/google/conscrypt) that Dataproc uses by default. To solve this issue you can disable Conscrypt using `dataproc:dataproc.conscrypt.provider.enable=false` [cluster property](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/cluster-properties) when creating a Dataproc cluster. If this will solve your issue, feel free to re-post your question for posterity and I can post an answer there too.

Comment: @Metadata FYI ^

Comment: @IgorDvorzhak So I should add a parameter to my cluster creating command like this:
`--properties=dataproc:dataproc.conscrypt.provider.enable=false` ....am I right ?

Comment: @Metadata yes, you are right.

Comment: @IgorDvorzhak Does the property you mentioned makes an insecure connection to the database ? Either way, your suggestion worked. Can you make it an answer ?

Comment: @Metadata no, this is not about security, this is about performance - Conscrypt is a faster implementation of some cryptographic algorithms than JDK 8 has, but MS SQL JDBC driver has some bugs that lead to incompatibility with it. I can not post is as an answer anymore because this question flagged as a duplicate already.

Comment: Posted as an answer on a new similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66282915/3227693