# Connect to SQL Server 2019 from Presto CLI

Tags: presto, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2019 from Presto CLI, I am getting SSL certificate error.

We have sql server 2019 hosted on google cloud on a VM and Presto on a dataproc cluster on the same project in google cloud.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does the connection code look like from Dataproc? Have you started here: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/network ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Dataproc to SQL Server(based on centos 7) connection error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66255107/google-dataproc-to-sql-serverbased-on-centos-7-connection-error)