# How to create dataframe in pyspark using odbc

Tags: pyspark, odbc, pyodbc

Need to create a dataframe.
Using pyspark or spark.
No use of pandas.
I m using odbc connection.

Comment: See this for reference: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58973960/2986344
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65184418/2986344

Comment: @teedak8s That's an example of JDBC. Could you point us to ODBC please.